# Select rows that are not urls using regexp?

Tags: sql, regex

I've tried multiple regexp's but still fetching rows that contains urls.

```
$fields=array(
":regexp"=>"/(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/"
);

$foo=$sql->prepare("SELECT * FROM names WHERE name NOT REGEXP :regexp");
$foo->execute($fields);
```

Comment: ftp, http and https are not the only schema's.

Comment: Some one explains the down vote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the regex  `.*?:\/\/[^ ]*?\.[^ ]*`

Answer (score -1):

are you using mysql? if so, the regex syntax is not PCRE (like your regex appears to be). it does not use the `/` delimiters.

also, if you're only testing for the *existence* of common urls, why isn't the domain part sufficient?

```
'[a-z]+://([a-z0-9]+(-+[a-z0-9]+)*\.)+[a-z]{2,}'
```